# Rounding Function is giving different result

Tags: javascript

I have this below code which will round the value to 2 decimal point. But when i have the below arguments, it is giving NaN.

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2");
}

let result = roundToTwo((171 * 0) - (-8.881784197001252e-16));

console.log(result);
```

Expected - **8.88** but giving **NaN**

Comment: The expected result is more like 0; the number you're passing is much much smaller than 8.88. For me it stops working at `e-7`. edit: heh, and that of course.

Comment: `num + "e+2" // "8.881784197001252e-16e+2"`

Comment: @ChrisG yes, that's true. It's about 16 orders of magnitude less.

Comment: Is there any solution which i can make generic for all

Comment: Don't do string concatenation (why??) but the actual operation you want: `* 100` and `/ 100`.